# JQuery validation and form submit - submit button needs to be pressed twice

Tags: jquery, jquery-validate

I am total newbie to javascript/jquery.

I am trying to validate a register form through JQuery, the validation works fine, but I have a little issue before submitting the form.

Exactly, the user has to press submit twice, first time, for the validation to run and second time to actually submit the form.

What's the solution to press submit once and the code to go through all validation rules and then submit the formular?

```js
$('document').ready(function()
{
    // name validation
    var nameregex = /^[a-zA-Z ]+$/;

    $.validator.addMethod("validname", function( value, element ) {
        return this.optional( element ) || nameregex.test( value );
    });

    // valid email pattern
    var eregex = /^([a-zA-Z0-9_\.\-\+])+\@(([a-zA-Z0-9\-])+\.)+([a-zA-Z0-9]{2,4})+$/;

    $.validator.addMethod("validemail", function( value, element ) {
        return this.optional( element ) || eregex.test( value );
    });

    $("#register-form").validate({

        rules:
        {
            name: {
                required: true,
                validname: true,
                minlength: 4
            },
            email: {
                required: true,
                email: true,
                validemail: true
            },
            mobile_number: {
                required: true
                //phoneUK: true
            },
        },
        messages:
        {
            name: {
                required: "Please enter your first name",
                validname: "Name must contain only alphabets and space",
                minlength: "Your name is too short"
            },
            email: {
                required: "Please enter e-mail address",
                validemail: "Enter a valid e-mail address"
            },
            mobile_number:{
                required: "Please enter a valid phone number"
            }
        },
        errorPlacement : function(error, element) {
            $(element).closest('.form-group').find('.help-block').html(error.html());
        },
        highlight : function(element) {
            $(element).closest('.form-group').removeClass('has-success').addClass('has-error');
        },
        unhighlight: function(element, errorClass, validClass) {
            $(element).closest('.form-group').removeClass('has-error').addClass('has-success');
            $(element).closest('.form-group').find('.help-block').html('');
        },

        submitHandler: function(form) {
            $("#register-form").on("submit", function (e) {
                e.preventDefault();

                var postData = new FormData($(this)[0]);
                var formURL = $(this).attr("action");
                var method = $(this).attr("method");

                $.ajax({
                    url: formURL,
                    type: method,
                    data: postData,
                    cache: false,
                    contentType: false,
                    processData: false,
                    success: function (data) {
                        $("#register_dialog .modal-header .modal-title").html("Thank you!");
                        $("#register_dialog .modal-body").html(data);
                        $("#submitForm").remove();
                    },
                    error: function (jqXHR, status, error) {
                        console.log(status + ": " + error);
                    }
                });
            });
        }
    });
})
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="http://ajax.microsoft.com/ajax/jquery.validate/1.7/jquery.validate.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/js/bootstrap.min.js"
            integrity="sha384-Tc5IQib027qvyjSMfHjOMaLkfuWVxZxUPnCJA7l2mCWNIpG9mGCD8wGNIcPD7Txa"
            crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
<div id="register_dialog" class="modal fade" tabindex="-1" role="dialog" aria-labelledby="register_dialog"
             aria-hidden="true">
            <div class="modal-dialog" role="document">
                <div class="modal-content modal-sm">
                    <div class="modal-header form-group">
                        <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal" aria-label="Close"><span
                                aria-hidden="true">&times;</span></button>
                        <h4 class="modal-title" id="registerDialogLabel">Registration form</h4>
                    </div>
                    <div class="modal-body">
                        <hr />
                        <form method="POST" id="register-form" name="register-form" action="form.php"
                              autocomplete="off">

                            <div class="form-group">
                                <div class="input-group">
                                    <div class="input-group-addon"><span class="glyphicon glyphicon-user"></span></div>
                                    <input type="text" class="form-control" name="name" id="name" minlength="3"
                                           placeholder="First Name"
                                           />
                                </div>
                                <span class="help-block" id="error"></span>
                            </div>

                            <div class="form-group">
                                <div class="input-group">
                                    <div class="input-group-addon"><span class="glyphicon glyphicon-envelope"></span></div>
                                    <input type="text" class="form-control" name="email" id="email"
                                           placeholder="E-mail address"
                                    />
                                </div>
                                <span class="help-block" id="error"></span>
                            </div>

                            <div class="form-group">
                                <div class="input-group">
                                    <div class="input-group-addon"><span class="glyphicon glyphicon-phone"></span></div>
                                    <input type="number"
                                           class="form-control" name="mobile_number" id="mobile_number"
                                           placeholder="Contact Number"
                                           />
                                    </div>
                                <span class="help-block" id="error"></span>
                            </div>

                            <hr/>
                            <button type="submit" class="btn btn-primary btn-fresh">
                                <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-log-in"></span> Submit
                            </button>
                        </form>
                    </div>
                    <div class="modal-footer"></div>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> the user has to press submit twice...

It's happening because you've put an `.on('submit')` within the plugin's `submitHandler` function:

```
submitHandler: function(form) {
    $("#register-form").on("submit", function (e) { // <- ?!
        e.preventDefault();
        ....
```

Effectively, this is a `submit` handler inside of a `submit` handler.

Remove the `.on('submit')` and you will instantly fix the "click twice" problem.  The plugin is already properly handling the critical events, and it's already blocking the default behavior so you don't need a `.preventDefault()`.  The `submitHandler` will only fire after the form is valid.

Also, you can simply use the `form` argument that's provided.

```
$("#register-form").validate({
    .....
    submitHandler: function(form) {
        var postData = new FormData($(form)),
            formURL = $(form).attr("action"),
            method = $(form).attr("method");

        $.ajax({
            ....
        });
        return false;
    }
});
```

Comment: I've tried your solution, it works untill the part that the data gets passed to form.php. I recive empty fields. I will continue to look into it. Thanks a lot.

Comment: @OctavianCristea, have you tried `$(form).serialize()` instead of `FormData()`?

Comment: @OctavianCristea, regardless, if you're not getting the data, then you seem to have a totally different problem within your ajax settings. I fully solved the original click-twice issue, which is the only thing you asked about

Answer (score 0):

I've solved the problem by changing the input type to text, for the mobile_number field and I added digits on that rule, but i still have the submit twice problem.

Comment: You only mention the 'submit twice' issue in your OP, so when you say *"I've solved the problem"*, what are you talking about?  It's like you've answered a totally different question.

Comment: I had two issues with that code, first was the validation of mobile_number field, <input type="number"> prevented the validation of the field at focusOut. The second problem was the submit twice issue.

Comment: My point is that you're answering a part of the question you never actually asked about.

Answer (score -1):

try action="javascript:;"

```
<form method="POST" id="register-form" name="register-form" action="javascript:;"
                                  autocomplete="off">
```

Comment: Please don't post a blind guess as an answer.